# IF statement syntax in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically what I'm trying to do is have the value in C7 shown if the cell isn't empty and if the the cell range C8:C16 contains only 0s. I'm using the code below but I can't get the syntax right

```
     =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C7))),AND(IF(ISBLANK(C8:C16))),c7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the formula is being put in a cell other than C7 and C8:16, then you could use this:

```
=IF(AND(C7<>"",COUNTIF(C8:C16,0)=9),C7)
```

This will check if both C7 is not blank and C8:C16 contains 9 zeroes (hence all contain 0), and only when the two are true, it will return the value from C7.

The syntax for `AND` is:

```
AND(expr1, expr2, ...)
```

Where `exprN` is an expression that returns a boolean value (true/false or `1/0`)

In case C7 is blank and/or C8:C16 contains a non-zero value, the above will return `FALSE`. If you want something specific instead, then use something like this perhaps:

```
=IF(AND(C7<>"",COUNTIF(C8:C16,0)=9),C7,"return this sentence if false")
```

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C7)),COUNTIF(C8:C16,"0")=5),C7,)`

You need `countif` to check how many values are 0. If checks only if one of them is 0.

Answer (score 0):

try this below formula

```
=IF(AND(SUM(C8:C16)=0,C7<>""),C7,"")
```

Comment: if you have -1 and 1 sum is 0.